# How to properly load a handmade Extension in Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm adding my own custom calculator, and I'm completely daft to how to properly assemble this.

[I'm sort of copying someone who had done the same thing](https://github.com/swistak/spree-price-bucket-shipping-calculator), but sans the official installation process.

My File structure looks very simple :

```
/extensions/
    calculators_extension.rb
    app/
      models/
        calculators/
          per_weight.rb
```

My preinitializer.rb loads them as so :

```
SPREE_EXTENSIONS_LOAD_ORDER = [:aged_revolt, :localization, :calculators, :theme_default]
```

**calculators_extension.rb**

```
def self.activate
  Dir.glob(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "../app/**/*_decorator*.rb")) do |c|
    Rails.env.production? ? require(c) : load(c)
  end

  Calculator::PerWeight.register

end
```

This return this :

```
/Users/macuser/Sites/age_of_revolt/aged_revolt/lib/aged_revolt.rb:14:in `activate': uninitialized constant Calculator::PerWeight (NameError)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your folder name should be calculator instead of calculators in models/calculators. Then only the naming convention would be correct.

Comment: Ha I just figured that out but big kudos to you Prince of all things Ruby. Thanks!